# How to add a root element to xml using groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

Hi I want to add root element before  And after

BEFORE

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

AFTER

```
<pad>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
</pad>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use [`StreamingMarkupBuilder`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/xml/StreamingMarkupBuilder.html) to add a root node.

```
def xml = """
            <note>
                <to>Tove</to>
                <from>Jani</from>
                <heading>Reminder</heading>
                <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
            </note>
          """

def nodes = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def markup = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder()

println markup.bind {
    pad { 
        mkp.yield nodes 
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, I have tried the above code, but still not able to add the parent node. Output is as below.      **<note>
                <to>Tove</to>
                <from>Jani</from>
                <heading>Reminder</heading>
                <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
            </note>**

Comment: Can you add what have you tried yet, to the question as an update? @user3463885

Comment: how about a string concatenation? :P